# What are the basic concepts behind "push" notifications / messaging?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

What are the key concepts that a developer should know when building an iPhone application that takes advantage of push notifications?

Comment: Edited your question to make it reference the iPhone, since, I assume that's what you're looking for.  If not, please edit your question with some more specifics.

Comment: Thanks Michael. It's 1:30am here and my brain is running less than optimally :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Number one most important thing, I think, is that your app can't depend on them. It's probably best to regard them as a nice thing for your *user*, rather than a part of your *app's* infrastructure. In particular:

- Apple doesn't guarantee delivery of the notices. Yes, their infrastructure is pretty good, but there's no promise.
- Only one alert can be up on the device at a time, and there's no log. So if the user has a bunch of push-enabled apps, you can't depend on them seeing your alerts.
- The only way that your app knows about a notice is if the user *chooses* to run it in response to an alert.
- The user can always turn push notices off, for your app, or for the whole device.

All of that also means: you can't cheat the "no background processes" restriction with the Push Notification Service. :-)

Comment: +1 - The details regarding the iPhone are parts I didn't know.